# how to get free Ubuntu OS?

Tags: 13.10

how to get free Ubuntu OS? I want to try the Salamander Version

I'm here in the Philippines.
I have my personal computer but my internet is so slow that's why
I can't download the file.

Any Helps are highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: if you can't able to download,then only option is to buy ubuntu cd from stores.

Comment: if you want to download click here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: You can try downloading using a download manager (like DownloadThemAll extension for Firefox) or using a torrent. It may take days on a slow connection but you'll get the big file in the end.

Comment: If you have limited bandwidth, it is probably better to use the long-term-support version (12.04, or 14.04 next year), which generally requires fewer updates. Short term releases like 13.10 are only supported for 9 months (vs 5 years for LTS) and therefore come with the implicit assumption you have enough bandwidth for a system upgrade (1GB or more) each time a new release is made.

Answer (score 0):

you can buy cd's from the [Ubuntu store](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976), but they [stopped to distribute free Cd's](http://www.ubuntu.com/shipit)

you can also look at the [LoCo team of the Philippines](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/loco-philippine-team/) and ask them whether they can give or sell you a installation Disc.

you could also try to download the ISO, with a unstable or slow connection I would advice to take a look at the [torrent downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). that way the download will resume if your connection drops.

edit: I did not realize you asked for 13.10 specifically, I think there are no physical discs for non- long term support releases.